# Nuitka with zeroMQ

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq, nuitka

I am trying to use Nuitka to compile a simple zeroMQ example and am having problems. I have used the following command to compile:

```
nuitka --standalone --portable --remove-output --recurse-all --python-version=3.4 testclient.py
```

and I get the following compile time warning:

```
Nuitka:WARNING:testclient.py:1: Cannot find 'zmq' as absolute import.
```

When I run the exe the run time error is:

```
ImportError: No module named 'zmq'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there an incompatibility with **`nuitka`** and **`zmq`**? ( The `testclient.py` works fine in the interpreter. )

Can anyone help with fixing this? ( I post this here instead of emailing the Nuitka author directly so others can learn from my difficulties aswell )

Using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python3.4.

Edit: Having similar problems using Windows 7 with Anaconda Python 3.4.

Comment: Have you, separately, installed the zmq library and the bindings? Often new users will miss one of these two first steps - you have to install the zmq library, as well as the bindings for your particular language.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm using pyzmq and it works fine in the python3.4 interpreter so zmq is definitely installed. Is this what you mean? Or is it the case that their are other steps e.g. installing extra source or header files?

Comment: If it's working in the interpreter then that should cover you so far as my question is concerned. Next on my list would be a permissions issue of some sort, though my impression is that both nuitka and the interpreter *should* be working with your user permissions.

Comment: Do you use virtualenv?

Comment: I have the same problem with nuitka 0.5.14.3 trying to package tornado app which works on python3.4. Reproduces both on virtualenv and without one.
Message is ImportError: No module named 'yaml'

Comment: I was using a virtualenv. I will try in a virtualbox instead with all dependencies available at system level. Will report back when I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract egg packages so that plain .py files are accessible.
You can do it by adding

```
[easy_install]
zip_ok = false
```

to your `~/.pydistutils`

and reinstalling dependencies.

For some reason nuitka 0.5.14.3 does not like compressed `.egg` files

Comment: Thank you. Will try this in the virtual box setup as mentioned in above comment and will report back.

Comment: how would you recommend doing this when I have installed from the anaconda stack? Is it possible to do after install? Is it possible to do in a reinstall? Or do I have to abandon anaconda and install everything one package at a time?

Comment: I would start with proper setup.py file listing all dependencies in it's packages directive. ( see https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html ) Then it could be used like 'python setup.py develop' to install everything you need. So yes, basically, abandon anaconda, probably it is not too hard